# Display AddError message on Contact Page

Tags: apex, before-trigger

Trying to display addError message on the Contact page but it's showing below error instead.
I want to display this message "You must remove the child records" instead. Need help! thanks!

[image]

Code for your reference:

```
For(Contact c : [Select id, (Select id from Communication_Contacts__r LIMIT 2) From Contact WHERE Id IN :conSet]){
        If(c.Communication_Contacts__r.size()>0){

            c.Id.addError('You must remove the child records');
            
        }  //end of For Loop

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `addError()` on every SObject instance, it must be a record from `Trigger.new`/`Trigger.newMap` (for insert and update trigger) or `Trigger.old`/`Trigger.oldMap` (for delete trigger).

[Trigger Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm) documentation states (emphasis mine):

> Triggers can be used to prevent DML operations from occurring by calling the `addError()` method on a record or field. **When used on `Trigger.new` records in `insert` and `update` triggers**, and on `Trigger.old` records in `delete` triggers, the custom error message is displayed in the application interface and logged.

[`addError()` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError) states (emphasis mine):

> Marks **a trigger record** with a custom error message and prevents any DML operation from occurring

Since it's a before update trigger, you can retrieve the record from `Trigger.newMap` via its id, then you'll be able to add the error message.

```java
for (Contact c : [SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM Communication_Contacts__r LIMIT 2) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conSet]) {
    if (c.Communication_Contacts__r.size()>0) {
        Trigger.newMap.get(c.Id).addError('You must remove the child records');
    }  //end of For Loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you @RubenDG